# Get All Samples from AudioData / Web Audio APIs

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm trying to create a scrollable display of the waveform for a video soundtrack, so I need to have all of the samples for the entire audio track available at once, and I would really prefer to not have to make an AJAX request for the binary media data just to get it in an arrayBuffer that JavaScript can use.
Is there any way with the Mozilla AudioData or webkit Web Audio APIs to get all of the samples for an audio track as soon as it's downloaded, rather than just getting streamed chunks during playback?

Comment: did you have any luck solving this problem?

Comment: Nope. The closest I could come is using decodeAudioData, but that doesn't work in Firefox. So, I'm just doing all my decoding in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `buffer.getChannelData(channel number)` to get the values for each sample in the buffer as an array.

Example:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', source, true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
request.onload = function () {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function (e) {
        var buffer = e;
        //gets the values for channel 1
        var sampledata = buffer.getChannelData(0);        
    });
};
request.send();
```